# Validation in XPages with Java

Tags: java, xpages

I have a Validator bean setup in Java where I can do the following:

```
public void validateStatus(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value.toString().equals("Fail")) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Invalid value!");
        throw new ValidatorException(message);
    }
}
```

And the XPage:

```
<xp:comboBox
    id="Status"
    validator="#{validatorsBean.validateStatus}">
</xp:comboBox>
<xp:message
    id="message2"
    for="Status">
</xp:message>
```

This is working great. However, I also want to do some validation logic and display an error message in a `<xp:messages>` control that is not associated with a specific field. Is there a way I can accomplish this in my Validator bean? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the line

```
throw new ValidatorException(message);
```

with

```
((UIInput)component).setValid(false);
facesContext.addMessage(component.getClientId(facesContext), message);
```

Comment: What parameter do I pass in for the component? I'm wanting to display an error message that is not associated with a specific field.

Comment: Use a hidden input field and add the validator to it.